# How to populate a Lookup fied according to a picklist

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, lookup

I have a Locations custom field = Lookup(Locations) which should be auto populated according to the value of the custom picklist field (Intial_Location).

Example:
Initial_Location__c = France
Locations__c = France (filled automatically)

I thought to process it via a Flow.
Does someone has and idea of the best way to build it?

Comment: You need some mapping then. You cannot fill Lookup with the value from the picklist. You should query Locations where some field is the equal value from picklist  (Initial_Location__c) and then fill Lookup with retrieved Id. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

We can populate the location based on the picklist value of Intial_Location__c
This can be implemented by using flow.
We can query the Location using get records element searched by Name comparing the value selected in the picklist
Based on the outcome we can update that in Lookup field.